# Isolated process Azure functions service bus trigger working locally but is not working in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-functions-isolated

My Service bus trigger function reads messages from a service bus topic

```
[Function("Posting")]
public async Task Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("topicnName", "subscriptionName",Connection = "AppSettings:SERVICE_BUS_CONNSTRING")]
         ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
         ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
{  

}
```

SERVICE_BUS_CONNSTRING is retrieved from Azure app configuration.  ***And this function is working locally but not in Azure.***

My application settings in Azure for worker runtime is set to dotnet-isolated

```
  {
    "name": "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME",
    "value": "dotnet-isolated",
    "slotSetting": false
  }
```

And my host.json is also configured as below:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": false,
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What versions of the Functions packages are you using?

Comment: what is the dotnet version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

I have created Isolated service bus topic trigger function
with runtime stack dotnet isolated.
By using below code able to read the messages from the service bus topic like below:

[image]

**function code:**

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp32323
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

        public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("firsttopic", "sample", Connection = "servicebusconnection")]
            ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
            ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Message ID: {id}", message.MessageId);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Body: {body}", message.Body);
            _logger.LogInformation("Message Content-Type: {contentType}", message.ContentType);

             // Complete the message
            await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
        }
    }
}
```

**local.settings.josn:**

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "servicebusconnection": "your-servicebus-conn-string",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
  }
}
```

**host.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

The above function executed successfully. check below:

[image]

I have published the above function into the azure portal.
[image]

[image]

Make sure to add service bus connection string in the appsettings of function app and check my configuration ln the below:

[image]

when i will send messages from the service bus topic got triggered in the portal like below:

**Output:**

[image]

[image]